# Django-storages S3: cname domains?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

Is there any way to use CNAME-domains with Django-storages' S3 backend? `AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN`  setting [suggested here](https://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/issue/48/allow-for-domain-cnames-to-s3) doesn't take effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN` works only for `s3boto` backend.